# getSharedPreferences not returning a value

Tags: android

I've placed a preferences file 'xml/sleeppreferences.xml' into a tabSpec, with the idea that that is the preferences for that part of the app and there will be other preference files for other parts.

This seems to work ok. I make a preference change, close the emulator, re-run the app, go back to the preference page, and the preference is what I had set it to.

But when I click to another tab, where I want to use the value of that preference, it all goes wrong.

I've looked high and low, but cannot find an answer.

This is an excerpt of the code:

```
public static final String PREF_FILE_NAME = "sleeppreferences";
:
:
:
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);        
String test=prefs.getString("editTextPref", "unset");
```

with "unset" being the default response if it doesn't find anything.

It always returns "unset"

As I say, I've looked all over, and the code I'm using seems to be the correct code. So what's going on?

Thanks

Dave

Comment: Post the code where you put the data into sharedpreference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the GetSharedPreferences of the context class. Something like this:

```
public  String GetPassword (Context Contexto, String Key) throws Exception
    {       

        SharedPreferences savedSession= Contexto.getSharedPreferences(Key,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return Encryption.decrypt(_Seed,savedSession.getString(Key, null));

    }
```

I think this should work as well:

```
getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).getString("editTextPref", "unset");
```

Comment: Sorry; String test=getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).getString("editTextPref", "unset"); still returned "unset". Thanks for the quick reply though. Dave

Comment: Could you add the code that you are using to save the preference inside the application?

Comment: My mistake entirely. Was saving the preferences to the default preferences rather than my custom one.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try this code to save your preferences and then use the code I previously pasted. It has to work fine.

```
SharedPreferences savedSession= context.getSharedPreferences(Key,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Editor editor = savedSession.edit();
    editor.putString(Key, EncryptedPass);
    editor.commit();
```